$f(x)=\int_{0}^{\alpha x} f(t)dt$ implies $f=0$
Let $\alpha \in [0,1[$ and $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $f(x)=\int_{0}^{\alpha x} f(t)dt$.
My goal is to prove that $f=0$. I showed that $f$ was infinitely differentiable and that for all $x\in \mathbb{R}, n \in \mathbb{N}^*$, $$f^{(n)}(x)={\alpha}^nf^{(n-1)}(\alpha x)={\alpha}^{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}f({\alpha}^n x)$$
which gives that as $n \rightarrow +\infty$, we have $f^{(n)}(x) \rightarrow 0$.
But I don't know where to go from here.

As $n \rightarrow \infty$,  $f^{(n)}(x) \rightarrow 0$ for any polynomial. It does not mean the function is identically zero.

Here I give a proof which follows OP's idea.
For any given $R>0$, we suppose
$$M=\max_{x\in[-R,R]}|f(x)|.$$
It is easy to see that $f$ is infinitely differentiable and
$$f^{(n)}(0)=0,\quad f^{(n)}(x)
={\alpha}^{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}f({\alpha}^n x),\quad n\in\mathbb N,x\in\mathbb R.$$
By Taylor theorem, when $x\in[-R,R]$, there exists $\xi_n$ between $0$ and $x$ such that
$$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}x^k
+\frac{f^{(n+1)}(\xi_n)}{(n+1)!}x^{n+1}
=\frac{f^{(n+1)}(\xi_n)}{(n+1)!}x^{n+1}
=\frac{{\alpha}^{\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2}}f({\alpha}^{n+1}\xi_n)}{(n+1)!}x^{n+1}.$$
So
$$|f(x)|\leq\frac{{\alpha}^{\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2}}M}{(n+1)!}R^{n+1}
\leq\frac{MR^{n+1}}{(n+1)!},\quad n\in\mathbb N,x\in[-R,R].$$
Let $n\to\infty$, we have
$$f(x)=0,\quad x\in[-R,R].$$
By the arbitrariness of $R$, we get $f\equiv0.$

Note that if we iterate the given formula we have $$f(x) = \int_0^{\alpha x} \int_0^{\alpha t_1} \ldots \int_0^{\alpha t_{n-1}}f(t_n)\mathrm{d}t_n\ldots \mathrm{d}t_1$$
for any $n\ge 1$. Since $f$ is continuous, $|f|$ is bounded on $[-1,1]$, say by $C$.
In the integral above, note that $t_n$ only takes values in $[0,\alpha^n x]$. Thus given $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and taking $n$ large enough that $[0,\alpha^n x] \subseteq [-1,1]$ we have $$|f(x)| \le \int_0^{\alpha x} \int_0^{\alpha t_1} \ldots \int_0^{\alpha t_{n-1}}C\mathrm{d}t_n\ldots \mathrm{d}t_1= C\frac{\alpha^n x^n}{n!}$$
which tends to 0 as $n\to \infty$.
